# Is it possible to reshard the data in an arangodb collection when add a new dbserver node?

Tags: cluster-computing, replication, arangodb

Since I am not sure how big my collection might grow in the future, I would like to know if I can add new dbserver node when required. 
there are two questions:
1. whether the data of collection will auto reshard from old dbaservers to the new one?
2. If so, are the resharding log appear in _api/replication/logger-follow?

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot reshard a collection. The proposed method is to backup the collection. Create a new collection with new sharding and restore it again.

Comment: This essentially makes the DB unusable for anything that cannot afford downtime and needs to scale.

Comment: Not true. You may start by using many more shards than database servers. I wrote a blog post about the idea of sharding: that might shed some light https://www.arangodb.com/2019/01/sharding-freedom-when-you-need-it-least/. The problem that one tries to solve with sharding is of course scalability. We decided to distribute as best as possible based on a sharding key.

Comment: Besides, you can always create a new cluster with different sharding, setup datacenter to datacenter replication and switch datacenters, when sync is done. Given the mindblowing importance of your app a negligable effort.

Comment: Disagree, "using many more shards" only moves the problem into the future. Sharding can only solve the scalability issue if the number of shards can be dynamically increased without stopping the DB service [as with other DBs]. Suggesting to migrate data is a very bad workaround for a deficient DB design and not a solution, besides DC-to-DC replication not being part of the free edition. As Arango has solved this, DB performance is miserable in the beginning because of too many shards, and when scaling is required, it's no longer possible without workarounds which cost time and money.

Comment: Which free version of anything cannot be taken down for maintenance with notice in advance? Storing nuclear codes? Running healthcare backbone in Beglium? Sounds enterprisy. I think I know, what the problem might be. It's me! I assumed that you were honestly looking for a solution.

Comment: Sorry Kaveh, don't understand. Does that mean the free version of Arango is not made for serious projects? Is it some sort of click-and-bait then?

Comment: Sorry @OliverHausler, serious like in Github with planned maintenance down times? Yes it is.